# Are there bounded surfaces without boundary that are noncompact?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am aware of the Heine-Borel theorem, which says that closed and bounded is the same as compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  My question is: are there (connected) surfaces **without boundary** embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are contained in a ball of finite size and yet are not compact?  In other words, to check if a bounded surface is closed is it enough to check that it has no boundary?

One possible counterexample might be [Alexander's horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere), but I'm having trouble determining whether or not it's compact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are plenty of counterexamples - the simplest ones are probably the open disc $$\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$$
and the open cylinder
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2=1,-1<z<1\}.$$
Both are connected, non-closed (hence non-compact), bounded surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without boundary.

Comment: I see -- I'm just confusing "without boundary" with "without 'holes'."  Thanks.